# Getting error while automating the PowerShell file in the task scheduler

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have created a PowerShell file, "File.ps1", and I am trying to automate the execution using the task schedular. As soon as the schedular is running, the PowerShell windows keep popping up but not running the script.

I have changed the execution policy to unrestricted for the script, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Can you add some more detail. Screen shots ?
Read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try something like `powershell file.ps1 > c:\windows\temp\file.log 2>&1`